# Center pager thumbs for slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slideshow

E.g. I have no problem centering manually if I have lets say 4 slide images so that generates 4 pager thumbs in the bottom middle of the slideshow, so you just adjust the pager with absolute position.

But what if a non-coder user decides to add extra slides, so that makes it 5 slides and one extra thumb generated, and each time the pager now e.g. goes left or right with each extra thumb.

How do I keep it centered no matter how many thumbs added or removed?

[image]

Like I said I just tried to absolute the pager container:

```
.region-slideshow .widget_pager_bottom {
  bottom: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  right: 490px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.region-slideshow .widget_pager_bottom .views_slideshow_pager_field_item {
  display: inline-block;
}
.region-slideshow .widget_pager_bottom .views_slideshow_pager_field_item .views-content-counter {
  background: url("../images/slideshow-pager.png") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 23px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 22px;
}
```

Comment: please show the code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap the pager with a div which is positioned absolute and takes the whole width. and in this div you will have your pager which is displayed inline with text-align: center.

your html:

```
<section class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
    ...
    </ul>
    <div class="slider-nav">
        <div class="pager">pagination here</div>
    </div>
</Section>
```

your css:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
}

.slider-nav {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.pager {
    display: inline;
}
```

if you are not able to manipulate the markup, you can center the pager by using negative margin-left in js/jquery on slider-init:

your html:

```
<section class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
    ...
    </ul>
    <div class="pager">pagination here</div>
</Section>
```

your css:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
}

.pager {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

your js/jquery on slider-start/init:

```
var pager = $('.pager');
var pagerWidth = pager.width();
pager.css('margin-left', (pagerWidth / 2) * -1);
```

Comment: Worked! All I needed was that width: 100%;